# Entity Framework 6 and Oracle 10g: Tables are imported, but no Entities created / updated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, oracle10g

I moved my Database from local development (Oracle 11) to a development server (10g). Then I tried to update my EF6 model (DB first), since 2 rows got added (regular `number(1,0)` rows). Opening the Model Browser, I do see the updates in the table, but the Entity is not updated accordingly. Removing the whole table and re-importing it, or creating a new model and re-importing the whole DB yields the same result. I am using VS2012, EF6, Oracle ODP.Net in its latest version (12.1.0.2.1).
Any ideas? Do I need additional privileges? Is there any way to have a "verbose" output from the model generation script? Any ideas and help are appreciated! Thank you

Edit: Let me add that creating the property manually and then mapping it works.

Comment: i don't know how about your ODP.Net Installed .
but maybe you need download full version with ODAC 
refer: 
http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm#s6

Comment: I've installed the whole bunch, including visual studio extensions etc. - as I wrote, it worked before switching from 11 to 10.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry about not see you had switching Oracle from 11 to 10 . but i read a official document . they mention Oracle 10 need least 10.2 version . what's your Oracle 10 version ? :)

Comment: it's 10g (the latest).

Comment: Check the Oracle Monitor as you're updating your model from your database.  Check that it is in fact querying the database you think it is.

Comment: It is. There is only one instance running - I deactivated the test environment completely (stopped the service, and when the error persisted I even uninstalled), it has no chance of using any other than the "right" DB connection.

Comment: Hi @Digifaktur  do you have installed any visualstudio plugin ? maybe you should stop it  and try again .  sometime the plugin will occur unexpected problems